# node redis passing data to callback

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using the redis npm module, I would like to pass some data (e.g. the index of a for loop) to the callback so that I can map local data(value at the time of the function call) to response data. Such as:

```
redisClient.get('a', [data1, data2], function(err, res, data1, data2){ 

/*more code */ 
})
```

I've gone over the doc, but couldn't find anything mentioning that.

Comment: Why can't u define an array outside and access it within  callback?

Comment: I can, but then how do I know which item in the array should the current callback execution access?

Answer (score 0):

```
function redisGet(_data1, _data2, callback){
  redisClient.get('a', function(err, res){ 
    callback(err, res, _data1, _data2)
  })
}

redisGet(data1, data2, function(err, res, data1, data2){ 

  /*more code*/ 
})
```

I ended up just simply wrapping the request in a function.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use promise instead because it's cleaner.

Below is a short example

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const redis = require('redis');
Promise.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

const client = redis.createClient() // U can put your redis credentials here.

async function someFunc() {
  try {
    for (const i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const result = await client.getAsync()
      // do stuffs with your result
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
  // handle your error
  }
}
```